# How to set Worksheet(sheet) to equal name in dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown list of possible titles I want the user to select from. These titles are the titles of the sheets in my workbook. Depending on the title selected I want to grab information from a table inside that sheet. My current code works fine with the Rocks sheet, which is sheet 2. I am able to get the correct values, but when I change the dropdown title, I only get #VALUE!. Is this because I am using Case incorrectly?

```
Function findTTY(color As String, distance As Integer, condition As String) As Integer

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim temp As Integer
Dim target As Integer
Dim range_col As Integer
Dim sheet_tab As String
Dim col As Integer
Dim dis_row As Integer


Select Case condition

    Case "Trees"
        sheet_tab = "Trees"
    Case "Rocks"
        sheet_tab = "Rocks"
    Case "Paint"
        sheet_tab = "Paint"
    Case "Boat"
        sheet_tab = "Boat"
    Case "Car"
        sheet_tab = "Car" 
End Select

For r = 1 To 100

    For c = 1 To 100
    
        If Worksheets(sheet_tab).Cells(r, c).Value = color Then
        
            For temp = 2 To 100
                
                If Worksheets(sheet_tab).Cells(temp + 1, c).Value - 1 >= distance And distance >= Worksheets(sheet_tab).Cells(temp, c).Value  Then
                
                    dis_row = temp

                    
                    Exit For
                End If
            
            Next temp
            
            For range_col = 1 To 100
                If Worksheets(sheet_tab).Cells(1, range_col).Value = "TTY" Then
                    col = range_col
                End If
                    
            Next range_col
                    
            findTTY = Worksheets(sheet_tab).Cells(dis_row, col)
                 
        End If
                          
    Next c
    
   
Next r

End Function
```

Comment: dist_row vs dis_row for a start. Put Option Explicit at the top of the code file. And not all paths through the code set the return value findTTY. If your test inside the For temp=2 to 100 loop isn't met, dist_row (or dis_row) is never set.

Comment: @DS_London Thank you for catching the dis_row. I forgot to mention that in the first spreadsheet I tell the user that the input value for distance has to fall between the range of the table to prevent any outliers I also changed the  temp =2 to 100 to temp = 2 to 99 for the case when temp = 99 there is a value it can look at (temp +1). With these changes I still am not able to get any values when changing the condition.

Comment: Maybe write a little Sub-routine to call your function from VBA ... then step through it in the Debugger (F8). Also, I'm not clear why you have the Select Case clause at all: you seem to be setting sheet_tab=condition whatever happens. If you are getting #VALUE! then it is likely one of your Worksheets(sheet_tab).Cells calls is bugging out and findTTY is never getting set. You could put a Case Else statement in, to catch if condition is not one of your choices (the = is case senstive). In that case, set findTTY to -1 (say) and call Exit Function.

Comment: @DS_London Did the charm.. turns out one of my tables had TTY + units which was producing a 0 for the column value and thus not giving me a output.. Thank you for helping me work through this issue!

Comment: Glad you got there!